# Sorting strings by a substring in Python

Tags: python, string, sorting, substring

I have a list of strings in python that looks like this:

- Name number number 4-digit number

How can I sort it by the last number?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your description is a bit unclear. Please post your data (or a part thereof) exactly how it's written in your code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like that:

```
sorted(your_list, lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]))
```

Comment: The second argument (optional) *must* be specified as keyword argument (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted). So `sorted(your_list, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]))`

Answer (score 22):

```
my_list = ['abc 12 34 3333',
           'def 21 43 2222',
           'fgh 21 43 1111']

my_list.sort(key=lambda x:int(x.split()[-1]))
```

`my_list` is now: `['fgh 21 43 1111', 'def 21 43 2222', 'abc 12 34 3333']`

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort_csv(lines=[], delim=',', position=1):
    '''
    Returns a sorted list based on "column" from csv-type data.
    '''
    return sorted(lines, key=lambda x: x.split(delim)[int(position) - 1])


test_data = [
        'part1/foo/part1/partX',
        'part3/bar/part5/partX',
        'part4/fuz/partA/partX',
        'part2/buz/part3/partX',
        ]
# Sort by third element
pprint(sort_csv(test_data, '/', 3))
#['part1/foo/part1/partX',
# 'part2/buz/part3/partX',
# 'part3/bar/part5/partX',
# 'part4/fuz/partA/partX']

test_data = [
        'abc 12 34 3333',
        'bar 53 29 AAAA',
        'def 21 43 2222',
        'foo 53 29 5555',
        'fgh 21 43 1111',
]
# Sort by last element
pprint(sort_csv(test_data, ' ', 0))
#['fgh 21 43 1111',
# 'def 21 43 2222',
# 'abc 12 34 3333',
# 'foo 53 29 5555',
# 'bar 53 29 AAAA']
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)